# Example of a function defined on [a,b], which is differentiable on $(a,b)$ & for which there is no $c$ with $f^{'}(c)= \frac{f(b)- f(a)}{b-a}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I know this has to do with the Mean Value theorem but since the function is not specified to be continuous then there does not exist a c. Would the function be a piecewise function where the endpoints are not differentiable but I'm not sure how this will show that there exist no c.

Comment: If it's differentiable on $(a,b)$, it's certainly continuous on $(a,b)$. The only thing that could possibly go wrong is if the function is not continuous at one or both of the endpoints.

Comment: Let $f(x)=x$ on $(a,b)$ and $f(a)=f(b)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ on the interval $(0,1]$, and then define $f(0)=0$.

Then
$$ \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=\frac{1-0}{1-0}=1>0$$

Yet clearly, on the interval $(0,1)$ the derivative $f'(x)=\frac{-1}{x^2}$ is never positive.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was given a down vote.  So +1 to neutralize it.

Comment: @Dr.MV thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It's differentiable on $(a,b)$, so it is continuous on $(a,b)$.  However, I see *no* constraint on the endpoints.  Set the endpoints to whatever.  For instance,

> $f(x) = \begin{cases}  0, &a <x < b \\ 2, &x=a \\ -2, &x=b \end{cases}$.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was given a down vote.  So +1 to neutralize it.

Comment: @Dr.MV : It's a mystery to me as well.  Bad enough to downvote, but not bad enough to snipe?

Comment: Not bad enough to downvote, hence +1 from me as well.

Comment: Yes Eric. I really can't abide by the happy trigger down voters on this site.  If the answer is perceived as "not useful," then why not leave a comment and permit the person who posted it to improve it?  I really just don't understand the rationale for down voting and very very rarely do so.  -Mark